# javascript function not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am having the issue with the below JavaScript function to be run on a form submit it works fine on ie. and Google groan but Firefox not running the second JavaScript function

```
 ItemAddMultiple: function (data, loadBasketPage, callBack) {

    var actionParams = {
        actionPath: "/bag/addmultiple",
        postData: { data: $.toJSON(data) },
        actionType: "add",
        loadBasketPage: loadBasketPage,
        callBack: callBack
    };

    NextBasket.AddBagAction(actionParams);
    NextBasket.GetFullRunMultibuyDiscount();

},
```

It is not running the `NextBasket.GetFullRunMultibuyDiscount();` function on firefox

Comment: Hit `Ctrl-Shift-J` to bring up the error console. Are there any errors in there?

Comment: Is `$.toJSON(data)` something you've implemented yourself, because that's not standard jQuery.  If not, change it to `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Comment: @mattytommo There is no native Javascript `.toJSON()`

Comment: @Archer There is, but it's for dates only, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON

Comment: @mattytommo So not objects, as in this question then? :p

Comment: @Archer Haha nah, I was just letting you know there was one :)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a `$.toJSON` in jQuery, you can use the JavaScript `JSON.stringify`, which is invoked by doing:

```
postData: { data: JSON.stringify(data) },
```